# map not loading when integrating google map api iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to show current location in my app using **Google Map API**.
I have used Google map API in our project I followed all steps  from "[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start)".

I have also given proper API key and bundle identifier but map is not loading only simple blank and last Google button show.

And I have used same API key in demo of "GoogleMaps-iOS-1.9.1" it's in proper worked but not load map on my app.

so, please give any suggestion or source code which is apply in my code.

Thank You.

Comment: have you added a app bundle id on the Google Maps Dashboard?

Answer (score -1):

Use following steps:

In AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Put your API key here.
    [GMSServices provideAPIKey:GOOGLE_PRJ_API_KEY];
    return YES;
}
```

Somewhere in your class say MapsController use following code in will appear:

```
- (void)setupGoogleMap{
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:_currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:_currentLocation.coordinate.longitude zoom:DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL];
    if (!_googleMapView) {
        _googleMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
        [self.view insertSubview:_googleMapView atIndex:0];
        _googleMapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
        _googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        [_googleMapView setDelegate:self];
    }
    _googleMapView.camera = camera;
}
```

Do check with your provided API keys or try regenerating or set of iOS only keys with bundle identifier